# Custom regression equation in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a set of data in R and I want to run a regression to test for correlation using custom coefficients.

Example:

```
x = lm(a ~ b + c + d, data=data, weights=weights)
```

That gives me coefficients for b, c, and d, but I just want to give b, c, and d my own coefficients and find, for example, the r^2. How would I do so?

Comment: r-squared is 1 - (sum of squared residuals)/(sum of squared deviations from the mean). You can calculate this for any chosen set of coefficient values to get an r-squared for each choice of coefficients.

Comment: I want to do it in R though because I want more numbers than just that, it's easier, and I want to weight the amount of times each input is counted.

Comment: You can still do it in `R`, but unless there's a pre-existing function to do what you want, you'd need to write a function to do the calculations.

Comment: Is that easy to do? I don't have a ton of experience with this.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your predetermined coefficients are a three-element, numeric vector named: `vec` and that none of a,b,c are factors or character vectors:

```
 #edit ... add a sum() function
(x = lm(a ~ 1, data=data, offset=apply(data, 1, function(x) {sum( c(1,x) * vec))} )
```

This should produce a model that has the specified estimates. You will probably need to do this:

```
 summary(x)
```

As always... if you want tested code, then provide a dataset for testing. With the mtcars dataframe:

```
m1 = lm(mpg ~ carb + wt, data=mtcars)
vec <- coef(m1)
(x = lm(mpg ~ 1, data=mtcars, 
                 offset=apply( mtcars[c("carb","wt")], 1, 
                                    function(x){ sum( c(1,x) *vec)} )))

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ 1, data = mtcars, offset = apply(mtcars[c("carb", 
    "wt")], 1, function(x) {
    sum( c(1, x) * vec)
}))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
  -7.85e-17
```

So the offset model (with the coefficients used in the offset) is essentially an exact fit to the m1 model.

Comment: Hmmm... ok. I'll probably try that later, thanks. For now I've just found the expected outcome (a hat in my example) in Excel and then transferred it to R where I can weight it by a separate variable, which gives me all the information I need.

Comment: @BondedDust, I couldn't get your method to work when I tried it out with the `mtcars` data frame. I'd be interested in seeing a working example with `mtcars` if you're willing to post one.

Answer (score 1):

@BondedDust's method will be more efficient in the long run, but just for illustration, here's a simple example of how to create your own function to calculate R-squared for any regression coefficients you choose. We'll use the `mtcars` data set, which is built into `R`.

Assume a regression model that predicts "mpg" using the independent variables "carb" and "wt". a, b, and c are the three regression parameters that we need to provide to the function.

```
# Function to calculate R-squared
R2 = function(a,b,c) {   

  # Calculate the residual sum of squares from the regression model
  SSresid =  sum(((a + b*mtcars$carb + c*mtcars$wt) - mtcars$mpg)^2)

  # Calculate the total sum of squares
  SStot = sum((mtcars$mpg - mean(mtcars$mpg))^2)

  # Calculate and return the R-squared for the regression model
  return(1 - SSresid/SStot)
}
```

Now let's run the function. First let's see if our function matches the R-squared calculated by `lm`. We'll do this by creating a regression model in `R`, then we'll use the coefficients from that model and calculate the R-squared using our function and see if it matches the output from `lm`:

```
# Create regression model
m1 = lm(mpg ~ carb + wt, data=mtcars)
summary(m1)

Call:
  lm(formula = mpg ~ carb + wt, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
  Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.5206 -2.1223 -0.0467  1.4551  5.9736 

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  37.7300     1.7602  21.435  < 2e-16 ***
  carb         -0.8215     0.3492  -2.353   0.0256 *  
  wt           -4.7646     0.5765  -8.265 4.12e-09 ***
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.839 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7924,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7781 
F-statistic: 55.36 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.255e-10
```

From the summary, we can see that the R-squared is 0.7924. Let's see what we get from the function we just created. All we need to do is feed our function the three regression coefficients listed in the summary above. We can hard-code those numbers, or we can extract the coefficients from the model object `m1` (which is what I've done below):

```
R2(coef(m1)[1], coef(m1)[2], coef(m1)[3])
[1] 0.7924425
```

Now let's calculate the R-squared for other choices of the regression coefficients:

```
a = 37; b = -1; c = -3.5
R2(a, b, c)
[1] 0.5277607

a = 37; b = -2; c = -5
R2(a, b, c)
[1] 0.0256494
```

To check lots of values of a parameter at once, you can, for example, use `sapply`. The code below will return the R-squared for values of `c` ranging from -7 to -3 in increments of 0.1 (with the other two parameters set to the the values returned by `lm`:

```
sapply(seq(-7,-3,0.1), function(x) R2(coef(m1)[1],coef(m1)[2],x))
```