# Build model object from a pre-specified model to check fit

Tags: r, regression, lm, summary

I have timeline data for inflation (`x1`) and output (`x2`) as well as the interest rate (`e`). I want to check how well the data for `x1` and `x2` fit to `e` when `e` is always supposed to be `e = 2 + 1.5x1 + 0.5x2.` Thus, *I do not want to run a linear regression* as the linear function you usually obtain from a `lm()` is *given* already (already not the least squared one).

How can I construct a model object from my known equation?

Using the model specified by my equation, I would check the fit (p-value, adjR²) via `summary()`. I could probably calculate the p-value and adjR² manually, but a simple command would make life much easier.

Comment: Hi Nivet! Welcome to SO. I feel like I'm not exactly sure what you data look like and what you're trying to do, but if you want some functions to get you started, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142643/8400969

Comment: Thank you Michael! As in your recommended link, I could certainly calculate the p-value and adjR² manually. But as this is a multi-variable function, this becomes quite complicated for me. Therefore, I would prefer a simple command similar to summary() that hands out the results in one piece.

Comment: Can you fix the model coefficients using `offset` and create the model object using `lm`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30626896/8400969; https://stackoverflow.com/a/27030807/8400969

Comment: I have tried, but using `offset` makes that `lm` does not treat them as variables anymore. Therefore, I don't get any information on their fit (especially p-value). Beside that, if I fix all the variables, it cannot calculate any adjR² either (which is obvious without any variables). 
To me the `lm` command does not seem right here, as I do not want to create a least-square regression line

Comment: Seems like an interesting problem. Have you looked around at `qr`?

Comment: Ah, ok, I totally misread your post before. Do you have an error term in your "known" regression model? Or is the error something you'd have to estimate from your data?